# PL/SQL insert into to table - random data from array

Tags: sql

I'm looking solution for my PL/SQL problem.

I want to enter data into a table at random.

```
array [0] = 'data1'; 
array [1] = 'data2'; 
array [2] = 'data3'; 
array [3] = 'data4'; 

insert into table (row) values ​​(array[$random]);
```

How to write it in PL/SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I find need information on this site http://zarez.net/?p=1288 and http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/29/sql-server-random-number-generator-script-sql-query/